# How do set rules for product price?

Tags: price, catalog-rules

I need to set rules for product prices. Rules will be applied to different customer groups.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the Promotions menu item on the admin panel.
You have 2 options there. Catalog price rules and cart price rules.
Both of them support different customer groups.
The catalog price rules are visible in the product list and view pages. You will see a promotional price if you have a rule applied to the product.
The shopping cart rules are only visible when you add a product to the cart.

Comment: Hi Marius, I'd hide the product price to the customer who are not logged in. Is it possibile with the standard feature? Thanks

Comment: Not i'm afraid. Search "hide price" at the magento connect or consider creating your own module.

Comment: You can hide the prices until the customer reaches the checkout. See the `Display Actual Price` attribute in the add/edit product form.